# How to make the window back to its original？

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

[image]

I just want to save my file
and I wrong button pressed.
The window becomes this.

Answer (score 1):

You've entered **Maximize View** mode - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> is the toggle shortcut.
You can also click that button on the top that says "back to previous":

[image: View]

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!